# Building a nested HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to build a nested hashmap in java like this

```
   {Customer:
             {
              Area:{}
             }     
      Bank:
            {
            City:{}
            }
   }
```

How can i do this?

Comment: what is your attempt ?

Comment: Why not create classes instead?

Comment: Have you tried `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` ?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what a HashMap is? This doesn't really seem like an appropriate use case. Please try explaining in more detail what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: it looks to me, u want JSONObject instead...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a map as the value of your outer map, like the following:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> nestedMap = new HashMap<> ();
Map<String, String> fooInnerMap = new HashMap<> (), barInnerMap = new HashMap<> ();
nestedMap.put ("foo", fooInnerMap);
nestedMap.put ("bar", barInnerMap);
```

However, this is not really convenient to use. If you want better answers, please specify what you want and what you tried.

Your data structure, for example, looks like JSON. If you need your Map to save or exchange data, you could use a JSON library.